# Hiding account form Open Org Chart in Dynamics 365 unified interface

Tags: dynamics-365

I'm using Ms Dynamics 365 online Version 9.1.00004626 for customer engagement.
On entity "account" form command bar in UCI, i have a button named Open Org chart this button doesn't appear in web classic interface. I need to hide it.

I tried with RibbonWorkBench, but i didn't see the button, i tried also xml customization file the button referenced by "ViewOrgChart", didn't appear.
How to hide this button?
Thanks for your help
Best Regards

Comment: The problem is solved. Just check in ribbonworkbench the tab name "tablet" and in the account form you will see the button. Just right click and hide.Thanks a lot. Regards

Comment: you can post your comment as answer & mark it.